# Unity: distância com addforce

Tags: c#, unity-5

Estou criando um jogo onde você aplica uma determinada força no bloco e ele anda verticalmente e tem que parar num determinado ponto e quero fazer isso pelo `AddForce`.

Porém, no papel, eu estou usando a formula:

```
distancia = velocidade ao quadrado/(aceleração vezes coeficiente de atrito)
```

E a distancia que o objeto percorre dá um valor diferente dessa formula. Queria resolver esse problema.

Observações:

- Drag ajustado para 0(o angular também).
- A velocidade de `Y` também varia quando o bloco mexe, mesmo que no `AddForce` eu esteja pedindo só a posição `X`.
- Não sei se interfere também, mas eu boto o bloco, em cima do plano, na posição 2D (10,-1) e quando inicio o jogo, ele é empurrado para posição (-10,00008, -0,9850087)

Comment: O objeto é disparado para cima ou para baixo ? Essa formula não me parece correta. Para calculo de posição tem a formula: `p = 0.5gt^2 + vt + p0`

Comment: Articuno: Neste caso o objeto é empurrado para direita, e não jogado para cima(Vector2.right*força). E não tem uma formula sem o tempo?

Comment: Tudo o que está relacionado a velocidade e aceleração está relacionado com o tempo. Isso já faz parte das leis da física mesmo.

Comment: Vlw gente =D, era essa duvida q eu tava tendo XD